# limit size image for ocr scan

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, ocr

I have a app client where the user upload a photo via native cam or canvas (PNG). In both cases the uploaded image is too large, about 6MB.
I have to pass this image to Google Vision for our scanning.

I have to limit the photo always at 5 MB. This because I support other services, for example Amazon recognition, where the limit is 5MB.

How I can to use imagemagick for this problem ?
I want use PNG because is probably better for the ocr, but I don’t want a static resolution, but I want only limit the size at little less of 5MB.

Comment: You might want to reconsider JPG for native cam captures, at least until you're able to preprocess the images. ImageMagick has `-define jpg:extent=5MB` option that is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: You can try my downsize bash unix imagemagick script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php